# Move contents of file to another file while writing to it

Tags: linux, move, named-pipes, truncate, fifo

I have a file in linux that is continuously being written by a named fifo pipe process. The file itself is not a pipe. I want to get the contents of the file and also remove the old contents of it without removing, moving, renaming the file itself. I can easily move the contents of that file without having to stop writing to it in various ways, using cat, or sed etc. and that's all good, but i don't want the content that i moved to also remain in the file. Because the file keeps growing, it will get too big at some point. I want to move and truncate the contents of a file without stopping the write process. The point of this is to get the contents of the file in one play so that i can zip it together with other similar files. The original file that is being written continuous must not be tinkered with or else the writing will stop. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Use [logrotate](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html), which can do exactly what you need. If that is not an option, consider checking out how it does it from its [source code](https://fedorahosted.org/logrotate/browser).

Comment: Logrotate restarts syslog after rotating the log files. This is not what Xndingo wants. He specifically wrote "I want to move and truncate the contents of a file without stopping the write process." - restarting the writing process would be stopping the write process IMHO.

Comment: Logrotate can copy and truncate a log file open for writing. Check the documentation

Comment: I've been looking into logrotate and it looks nice. But i don't understand how i can use it with my files. I have lots of csv files that data keeps appending to them, for example data1.csv, data2.csv, data3.csv ... etc. How can i use logrotate with them?

Comment: Ah. I was looking at how logrotate is being used with syslog. From copytruncate description I see that there might be some logged data that is lost as part of this operation.

Comment: yes, i don't like the trucnatecopy option cause in that time some data will be lost. If possible i have no problem rotating my csvs but i don't actually know how to rotate them. They are generated from another script.